# Nodejs module.parent condition not working on ubuntu server

Tags: node.js, plesk

I am working on an existing project and found this piece of code in my app.js

```
//if (!module.parent) {
  // Server listen
  app.listen(mysettings.port, function () {
    console.log(`Server ready at ${ENV}:${mysettings.port}`);
  });
//}
```

When I run locally, app.listen hits and my project runs, when I upload my project on a ubuntu server, the project does not run, but times out. When I comment out the condition on ubuntu the project runs perfectly. I know on my localhost, module.parent is null.

Any help would be apperciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "*upload my project on a ubuntu server*"? How is your script executed by that server? And how do you execute it locally?

Comment: Do you understand what the condition does? And is it even necessary in your project?

Comment: @Bergi I have no idea what the condition does or if it is necessary to the project. Locally, I would use npm i, then npm start...on this ubuntu server, we are using something called Plesk (first time using it) basically you upload your project and then in the Plesk dashboard there is an option to enable nodejs and you tell it where the path is and what the file is called, then are options to restart app, npm install, run a scrip (using build) and it runs.

Comment: For the purpose of the condition, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6398196/1048572). Maybe ask the developer who originally added it? As for plesk, I have no idea.

Comment: #1 Did you solve your problem? #2 If your current team don't have knowledge about plesk **AND** your app is classic nodejs (web or api), use docker instead plesk.I can help you . #3 Could you verify if plesk is the problem?

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(module.parent)` and post here the output? I am wondering what it looks like.

Comment: @user979331 the ubuntu server is most likely using `require` to get your scripts.. meaning that the app won't run, meaning that it will time out.. may I ask WHY you have that condition? what would you do if your script has a parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This maybe works for you:

```
if ((!module.parent) || (("exports" in module.parent) && ("PhusionPassenger" in module.parent.exports))) {
  // Server listen
  app.listen(mysettings.port, function () {
    console.log(`Server ready at ${ENV}:${mysettings.port}`);
  });
}
```

`module.parent` is `null` when your `app.js` is called directly from node just as in `node app.js`.

I believe Plesk utilizes PhusionPassenger under the hood (at least Plesk official node.js extension which is probably your case). Being this the case, your app is probably called with the command `passenger start --app-type node --startup-file app.js` which pre-loads a script `node-loader.js` before yours, which becomes your `module.parent`.

If you want the same behaviour for both direct node and Passenger's call, then you have to replace every `(!module.parent)` filter in your code with `(!module.parent) || (("exports" in module.parent) && ("PhusionPassenger" in module.parent.exports))`. By doing this you will keep avoiding the situations the original developer probably intended to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

"times out" generally means that it cannot bind a port.

Likely you'd have to fix the environment, in order to access the desired `ENV` values.
Try setting the environment globally (requires a reboot before this is being picked up):

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

Also make sure that `mysettings.port` is even accessible / not in use by something else.
This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63880712/549372) appears related, so there may even be two ways how to define the environment.
(my answer is rather the Linux version - and the linked answer seems to be the Plesk version). When loading from file, there still is the chance that one has suitable values - and the other one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

**module.parent** is a special property that's set by Node when you require() a module. It's a reference to the module that required this one.
If you're the top-level module, it's `null`. If you're a child module, it's the parent module. If you're a grandchild, it's the grandparent. And so on.

```
// $ node app.js
console.log(module.parent); // `null`

// require('./app')
console.log(module.parent); // `{ ... }`
```