# Environment Variables on Plesk Nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hosting, web-hosting, plesk

I have hosted my node api on Plesk. But i cant find anywhere to add my env variables so that my api could work.

As you can see in the below image. custom variables option is below `Application Startup File` but in my case its not there.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Plesk for Linux only) Custom environment variables - Here you can see a list of custom environment variables you have set for your application (if any). Click “[specify]” to add or remove environment variables for your application:

- Click Add variable to add another environment variable to the list.
- Type in the variable name in the left field, and its desired value in
  the right.
- Edit the variables already on the list by clicking the corresponding
  field and typing in the new variable name or value.
- Click Remove next to a variable to remove it from the list.

If you running Plesk on Linux env then the above option is available else you need to follow the below steps.

You need to use `.env` outside the application folder and create a custom script and pass these `.env` and send them as arguments when you run the node script. [Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63737597/node-app-on-plesk-environment-variables-on-custom-scripts) this link if it helps.

Comment: my plesk is windows i guess

Comment: Yes, follow the steps with .env file that should solve it.